# How do I create a group name in google chat for my team?

Tags: google-hangouts

In a new Google chat, how do I name a group chat? (3 people in the supervisor chat group)

Once I name the group, how do I find the group when creating a new chat or at a new log in?

Comment: If you want a chat with a name, you should create a new `ROOM` instead of a new `CHAT`.

Comment: Thank you, I figured this out, I have created a couple rooms for my groups, now some of the people in my teams do not have the tasks tab in the room...I have asked our IT dept to turn tasks on for these people, we will see if this works...'Thank you